# How do you use an input (within an if statement) from one procedure with a different procedure

Tags: python, input, authentication, server, procedure

## My project is making a login server using txt files to store user info, and trace back, to complete logins.

However I am trying to use the statement, **(if new_username == username)**. I want to use the username they already created and the one they just entered. However these 2 inputs are in different procedures. And because of this it wont let me use another input from a different procedure.
If there are any changes or edits I can make to the code to overcome this issue, I would greatly appreciate it!

[my code, and with drawings to explain what im talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEfX7.jpg)

[original image of my code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKetR.jpg)

Comment: Don't use screenshots

Answer (score 2):

**Your test is not true, you should use username and password as a global variable.**

**Try this :**

```
  def register():
        username = input("Please enter your username ")
        password = input("Please enter your password ")
        file = open("login.txt","a")
        file.write(username+" "+password+"\n")
        file.close()


    def login():
        username = input("Please enter your username ")
        password = input("Please enter your password ")  
        for line in open("login.txt","r").readlines(): 
            login_info = line.split() 
            if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
                print("Correct credentials!")
                return True
        print("Incorrect credentials.")
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your newUser() function you will have to assign the variables you have used e.g. 'username' as global. This will allow you to use and access the variable outside of the current procedure.

```
def newUser():
    global username 
    username = input("Create login name: ")
```

Do this with every variable you want to access outside of the current procedure.

Ideally, if you're going to be doing this a lot in your program, you might want to take a look at using classes.